# trigger lambda based on specific filename (like *.xlsx) upload in s3 folder and dont trigger when (*__processed.xlsx) is uploaded in same s3 folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

We have lambda function to run only when .

1. A file is uploaded in s3 (`*.xlsx`) and then we process it via lambda.
2. After processing the file will again come here only this time filename will be `*_processed.xlsx`. Now this time is there a way the lambda is not triggered?

I see only prefix where I will pass folder name and suffix where I can pass .xlsx.

Any suggestion if this requirement can be made possible?

Comment: Do you have control over the upload of the file?

Comment: no we cannot control the file upload

Comment: Ok. Then just use a different bucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where I will pass folder name and suffix where I can pass .xlsx.

Nowhere. Such filtering is **not supported** in S3 events. You need to setup an extra lambda function which will do the filtering that you want, and then push it forward to your next lambda:

```
S3 ---> Lambda Filter ---> SQS ----> Processing lambda
```

Comment: It might be possible using S3 EventBridge notifications https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-use-amazon-s3-event-notifications-with-amazon-eventbridge/ and EventBridge filters https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html instead of direct S3 to Lambda notifications.

Comment: @MarkB I just checked that actually. EventBridge doesn't offer any string-matching functionality that could help here unfortunately, so it can't be used either.

Comment: @Paolo yeah I think you are right. In that case this answer is correct, you would need custom code (via a Lambda function) to implement the desired filtering.